# hapijs v17 set header before sending response in plugin

Tags: ecmascript-6, cors, hapi.js

I want to create a HapiJS plugin for v17 to append to the response some custom headers, for cors but shouldn't matter.

```
const cors = {
    name: 'cors',
    version: '1.0.0',
    async register(server) {
        logger.debug('Initiating CORS internal plugin...');
        const { port } = server;
        originPort = port;

        server.ext('onPreResponse', async (request, h) => {

        return h
            .response()
            .header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', resOrigin)
            .header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE')
            .header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, X-Requested-With, Authorization')
            .header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
            .header('Access-Control-Max-Age', 1728000);
    });
},
```

};

Here's what I have so far. I don't think it's right as I get an error.

I've also tried:

```
  server.ext('onPreResponse', async (request, h) => {
        const { response } = request;

        response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', resOrigin);
        response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE');
        response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, X-Requested-With, Authorization');
        response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
        response.header('Access-Control-Max-Age', 1728000);

        return h.continue;
   });
```

This seems to work locally but fails during testing.

```
console.error node_modules/hapi/lib/core.js:126
    Debug: internal, implementation, error 
        TypeError: response.header is not a function
        at header (/home/node/app/src/lib/cors.js:47:22)
        at <anonymous>
        at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)
```

How do I acheive this in HapiJS v17? The API appears to have been completely refactored in this version and there is very little examples of what specifically I'm trying to do in this version of Hapi.

Thanks!

Comment: Try response.setHeader(). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48016014/response-header-error-in-node-server and https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value

Comment: No dice @sideshowbarker

Debug: internal, implementation, error 
TypeError: response.setHeader is not a function
at server.ext (/home/node/app/src/lib/cors.js:47:22)
at <anonymous>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you return Boom errors your response behaviour changes. Try this.

```
exports.plugin = {
    async register(server, options) {
        server.ext('onPreResponse', async (request, h) => {
            const {response} = request;

            if (response.isBoom) {
                response.output.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true';
                response.output.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE';
            } else {
                response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
                response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE');
            }

            return h.continue;
        });
    },
    name: 'cors'        
};
```

Comment: I do have Boom errors thrown in my code I believe this is the issues. Thanks.

Comment: Hi metoikos, any idea how to delete the key and value pair entirely?